# How to take String of a JComboBox Event handler into a variable for query?

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jcombobox

In the JCombobox are possible Routes for a train.I want to get the value of JCombobox based on the event handler and then use it in a class that uses a Database. This value will be a parameter for a Mysql query.I have succeeded in getting it,but can not use it. I'm not very experienced in java, I am doing something wrong. I have searched the site for similar problems, seen them but not understood them clearly.What am I missing?

```
//imports...

public class Cashier extends JFrame{

      //here is main...
 public Cashier(){

      //some Window code...

     final  String[] Routes = {"--Select--", "value1",....."valueN" };
     final JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(Routes);

     comboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
       /*-->*/ public String d; 
            public void WhereTo(String dest){

                 this.d=dest;                 
                   System.out.println(d); 

          // comes out correct!           
      /*I want d for use in DBaccess class as query parameter, by invoking 
        GetRoute()*/         
}            

         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                 int val = comboBox.getSelectedIndex();
                         this.d= Routes[val];    
              WhereTo(d);

        }         
     });
            comboBox.setBounds(165, 124, 130, 23);     
    contentPane.add(comboBox);

   //this method will be used by DBaccess

   public String GetRoute(){

     return d;                    
    }

    //More Objects...
  }
}
```

This is my DBaccess class where i want to use the string d, probably by invoking Get Route() of Cashier.

```
 public DBaccess extends Cashier{

  //connection code....

 // Executing the query
  System.out.println("Creating statement...");
  stmt = conn.createStatement();
  String sql; 

 //probably like this...   
 String go = Cashier.GetRoute();

  sql = "SELECT FROM reservations WHERE destination='"+go+"'";
  ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
  }
```

Comment: Please try to describe your exact problem. Does your code compile? Does it run? Does it produce a result? Is this result different from what you expected?

Comment: neoprez --- I declared as you said but also had to make it static, inluding GetRoute. Yes it compiles, now! but the value is null in DBaccess though. Cannot make the query!

Comment: All in all, I am trying to pass d to DBaccess to make the query

Comment: Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  To organize the components for a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556), along with layout padding & borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17874717/418556).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
String go = Cashier.GetRoute();
```

This method is not static and it can't be invoked in this way. In any case it's a poor design choice. Consider providing `DBaccess` class with a setter for the desired route. The `actionPerformed()` implementation should look like this:

```
@override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    JComboBox comboBox = (JComboBox)e.getSource();
    String selectedRoute = (String)comboBox.getSelectedItem();
    DBaccess dbAccess = new DBaccess();
    dbAccess.setRoute(selectedRoute);
    dbAccess.setVisible(true);
}
```

Some tips to help you:

- `Cashier extends JFrame`: don't extend from swing components if you won't add some Swing related functionality. You can use a simple variable instead.
- `DBaccess extends Cashier` (which extends from [JFrame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html)): a tipical Swing application should have only one `JFrame`. You should use [JDialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html) instead. See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice)
- Provide `DBaccess` class with a method to set the desired route from another class (`Cashier`).
- The query you're trying to execute is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. Take a look to [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) to avoid this.
- If `DBaccess` class will display the query results using Swing components, then you may want to take a look to [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) class to do the database call in a background thread and update Swing components in the [Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html). Take a look to [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) trail for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Make d a Global class variable. By saying this I mean, declare it right after the class name.

```
public class Cashier extends JFrame{
private String d;
  //here is main...
 public Cashier(){
//some Window code...

 final  String[] Routes = {"--Select--", "value1",....."valueN" };
 final JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(Routes);

 comboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   /*-->*/ public String d; 
        public void WhereTo(String dest){

             Cashier.this.d=dest;   //to change d value              
               System.out.println(d); 

      // comes out correct!           
  /*I want d for use in DBaccess class as query parameter, by invoking 
    GetRoute()*/
```

}

```
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             int val = comboBox.getSelectedIndex();
                     Cashier.this.d= Routes[val];   //to change d value 
          WhereTo(d);

    }         
 });
        comboBox.setBounds(165, 124, 130, 23);     
contentPane.add(comboBox);
```

//this method will be used by DBaccess

public String GetRoute(){

```
 return d;                    
}

//More Objects...
```

}
}

Comment: Had to change it to (private static d) and the method to (private static String GetRoute()) ,ok. But then i have the d declared in the ActionListener and the static one ,have to connect them some how...

Comment: I;m trying to find the way to pass d from one class to the other, Cashier to DBaccess to make the query.